# MCP1612 - circuit debugging

Tags: voltage, voltage-regulator, layout

I am designing an adjustable voltage regulator using [MCP1612](https://www.mouser.tw/datasheet/2/268/MCHPS04250_1-2520750.pdf) and DAC signal from a microcontroller. I designed the following schematic and PCB (I tried to cut out only the relevant part)
[image]
[image]

The resistor with the port REG_FB is supposed to be used as the DAC adjustment line. The header in the upper-right corner of the PCB is used to switch between ON/OFF using a jumper.

However, when I tried soldering on all the components and doing a simple test (Vin= 5V, no load), the regulator IC clearly burned and died. Thus I tried soldering only the regulator (brand new one) on the PCB and undertake some debugging measurements. The thing that felt weird to me is the resistance on resistor pads R12 (without the resistor present), where a resistance of 100kΩ was measured.

I wonder if someone could spot an evident mistake in the design or suggest a method to find the layout error.

Please take the design as a hobbyist design (I know it's nowhere near to being perfect), thus I would appreciate a suggestion, that would fix my issue, not improve parameters (noise, interference).

Comment: What was your input voltage for the test?  Did you calculate the (only) 1uH inductor?

Comment: The 100k resistance measurement was without any input voltage. If you are asking about the test, when it burned, the input voltage was 5V, while the inductor was 3.3uH. The test was under no load (and it burned under no load) so I suppose the inductor value is here irrelevant. EDIT: I mean irrelevant to the issue.